# Make A POST Including a HTTP Basic Authorization header via PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

## Instruction

Making a post request with content-type x-www-form-urlencoded to the following URL:https://api/openid/token/revokeToken 
including a HTTP Basic Authorization header, consisting of a base64 encoding of username:password

***The call should issue 200 OK responses even when the token is not recognized. Errors are communicated to the client using the response body.***

## Tries

I tried

```
$OPENID_TOKEN_REVOKE_URL = 'https://api/openid/token/revokeToken';
$auth_code = base64_encode('username:password'); //dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$OPENID_TOKEN_REVOKE_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth_code);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));


// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

dd($server_output);
```

I got

```
"<html><head><title></title></head><body>15058752898584540867</body></html>"
```

---

I also try

```
$headers = array(
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization: Basic " . $auth_code
  );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$OPENID_TOKEN_REVOKE_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

dd($server_output);
```

I got same result as above

```
"<html><head><title></title></head><body>15058752898584540867</body></html>"
```

---

According to the instruction from my iDP

***"Errors are communicated to the client using the response body"***

Is that mean an error base on what I got back from my cURL ?

Comment: May be have a look at this user note here http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#80271, creating the full auth header and set it with set opt CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Comment: Thanks. I did that now. I got same result `<html><head><title></title></head><body>15058752898584686828</body></html>`

Comment: Is that mean it is working or error ? Please kindly advise, I don't know much about cURL responses or behavior of output. :(

Comment: How do we know our POST actually really did a POST ? At lease, we know for sure that my end is correct. Is there any 200 reponse I should get ?

Comment: Using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`really should do a post. if you're unsure, check it with wirshark/tcpdump, ... a test request on a page you code yourself...

Comment: Use `curl_getinfo($`ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );` to get the HTTP response code. 200 for a normal response. With `curl_getinfo` you can get many info.